# Como abrir a imagem na galeria clicando em cima dela pela minha aplicação?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, imagem

Meu aplicativo tem um botão que quando é pressionado é aberto a câmera, assim que eu tiro a foto, ela é colocada em um ImageView na tela e o caminho da imagem é salvo no meu banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como faz para quando eu clicar na imagem na tela, ela abrir na galeria com o tamanho normal da imagem, porque no meu aplicativo ela fica pequena. Lembrando, tenho o caminho da imagem no banco de dados: "/storage/sdcard/1442199864328.jpg".

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um método que chamando o app Galeria usando a classe Intent. Crie um onClick no seu ImageView e chame o aplicativo de imagens pelo Intent. 
Exemplo:

```
public void visualizarImagem(){
imageView.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
@Override
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri img = Uri.parse("file://" + caminhodafoto);
intent.setDataAndType(img, "imagem/*");
startActivity(intent);}
}
);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado sparkss, deu certo.

Comment: Opa, de nada Yuri.